# Ext js - Disable grid rendering even when store is loaded?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, sencha-touch

I have a grid which is bound with a store. The store is again bounded with other component.

The store is loaded from a remote service returning thousands of records which crashes the browser as it is bounded with grid and a combo box.

What I want is to disable rendering of the grid when the store is loaded. I do not want to unbind the store from the grid or empty it as it is connected with a combo box.

Things I have tried:

```
gridObj.setVisible(false)
```

It still renders the data. It is just hidden.

```
document.getElementById(gridObj.el.id).remove()
```

The grid elements are removed from dom but it still crashes the browser as store must be processing the grid components(my guess).

```
gridObj.getStore().removeAll()
```

Grid is empty. Grid DOM is also not there(yay!) but browser still crashes.

So is there any store or grid method which will not render the grid still keeping it connected with the store. Or any DOM manipulation so the grid is not rendered and store does not process the data on grid.

Answer (score -1):

Your crashing the dom because you don't have this on your grid:
 bufferedRenderer: true

Honestly, I thought you could simply set the grid visibility to false like you had and that would work.  But since it is not, stick a container/panel around your grid in your view.  Give it a reference and set the container visibility to false.  That will definitely take care of it.